# PHP - recursively iterate over json objects

Tags: php, json, object

I need to iterate over objects in PHP and to apply a certain function on each and every single value in this object.
The objects are absolutely arbitrary. They can include vars, another objects, arrays, arrays of objects and so on...

Is there a generic method to do so? If yes, how?

Usage example:
RESTful API which receives requests in JSON format.
json_decode() is executed on request body and creates an arbitrary object.
Now, it is good, for example, to execute mysqli_real_escape_string() on every value in this object before further validations.

OBJECT EXAMPLE:

```
{
  "_id": "551a78c500eed4fa853870fc",
  "index": 0,
  "guid": "f35a0b22-05b3-4f07-a3b5-1a319a663200",
  "isActive": false,
  "balance": "$3,312.76",
  "age": 33,
  "name": "Wolf Oconnor",
  "gender": "male",
  "company": "CHORIZON",
  "email": "wolfoconnor@chorizon.com",
  "phone": "+1 (958) 479-2837",
  "address": "696 Moore Street, Coaldale, Kansas, 9597",
  "registered": "2015-01-20T03:39:28 -02:00",
  "latitude": 15.764928,
  "longitude": -125.084813,
  "tags": [
    "id",
    "nulla",
    "tempor",
    "do",
    "nulla",
    "laboris",
    "consequat"
  ],
  "friends": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Casey Dominguez"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Morton Rich"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Marla Parsons"
    }
  ],
  "greeting": "Hello, Wolf Oconnor! You have 3 unread messages."
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example object? That sure would make it easier.

Comment: The objects are too long to fill in the comment box. :(
Basically, they are very big and I need to apply some generic validations.

Comment: Use of `mysqli_real_escape_string()` would be unnecessary if you were using bind variables in your SQL code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to walk over the data and won't need to re-encode it, [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)'s second parameter, `$assoc` will cause it to return an associative array. From there, [`array_walk_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) should work well for what you're after.

```
$data = json_decode($source_object);
$success = array_walk_recursive($data, "my_validate");

function my_validate($value, $key){
    //Do validation.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function RecursiveStuff($value, $callable) 
{
   if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) 
   {
       foreach (&$prop in $value) {
          $prop = RecursiveStuff($prop);
       }
   } 
   else {
       $value = call_user_func($callable, $value);
   }
   return $value;
}
```

And use it like:

```
$decodedObject = RecursiveStuff($decodedObject, function($value) 
{
   return escapesomething($value); // do something with value here
});
```

You can just pass function name like:

```
$decodedObject = RecursiveStuff($decodedObject, 'mysqli_real_escape_string');
```

Comment: You got errors it should be:
...`foreach ($value as &$prop) { $prop = RecursiveStuff($prop, $callable);`...